Windows audio changes volume a few minutes after turning off TV
I have this strange issue with my TV and Windows 10 PC, they are connected via HDMI through an NVidia card.
After I turn off the TV, it seems to switch volume.
It seems like it either switches sound drivers, or sound devices.
But I only see one device visible in sound devices which is NVIDIA High Definition Audio
If I have the volume set to 50%, after the TV turns off a few minutes later it jumps to the other device. Which is usually set to 100%. However, if I set the other device down to 0%. It will jump from 50% to 0%, and back to 50% when I turn the TV on.
Another thing is that I sometimes see the volume level jump around between the two volumes when I open the volume Icon.
No idea how to fix this. I think the TV puts the graphics card to sleep maybe it switches to a built in sound card from the gfx sound card but somehow routes it to the same HDMI port?


what exactly is the problem?

"If I have the volume set to 50%, after the TV turns off a few minutes later it jumps to the other device. Which is usually set to 100%. However, if I set the other device down to 0%. It will jump from 50% to 0%, and back to 50% when I turn the TV on."

it remembers the volume setting for each device ... how is that a problem?
